# AngularJS - ng-if a field is focused

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<input class="user" ng-model="user" />
<div class="matches">
    <div class="match" ng-repeat="match in matches | filter:user" ng-bind="match"></div>
</div>
```

I only want to show `.matches` IF you are typing and searching for a `user`. Otherwise, I don't want to show the field. But the `input` field is always displaying the `user` (so I can't use the fact that the input is empty or not).

Is there a way I can use the fact that the `input` is focused directly? Right now, I manually update a value `ng-if="isFocused"` when you focus in and out.

Comment: No, because `input` is to always be displayed. It can change its value. Actually let me update my question to be a bit more clear. Basically, `input` always has a value. You click it to change its value, and that is when matches should show up

Comment: A dirrctive can help you in this one

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing at the moment. I wanted to see if there was another way of using more built-in commands

Comment: May be just use CSS and :focus?

Comment: The title describes the question perfectly. The text is distracting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="focused = true" ng-blur="focused = false" />

<p ng-if="focused">focused!</p>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/docikiyRlYNOu5OGb1PE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
<input class="user" ng-model="user" />
<div class="matches">
    <div class="match" ng-if="user!=''" ng-repeat="match in matches | filter:user" ng-bind="match"></div>
</div>
```